# can't insert variable session to database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, session

Here is Controller

```
public function add(){

    $npp=$this->session->userdata('NPP');

    $mpwp=$this->input->post('mpwp');

    $ket=$this->input->post('ket');

    $data = array(
       'npp'=>$npp,
       'tgl_pengajuan' => date('y-m-d'),
       'ket' => $ket,
        'status' => 'P' 
       'mpwp'=>$mpwp,
     );

    $this->Cutimpwp_Model->add($data);

    redirect('cutiMpwp');
  }
```

Here is Model

```
function add($data) {
  $this->db->insert('cuti_mpwp',$data);
}
```

Here is View

```
<div class="form_row">
<label class="field_name">mpwp</label>
<div class="field">
<input type="text"  name="mpwp"  class="input-large"   value="<?php echo set_value('mpwp'); ?>" placeholder="masukan nama"> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="form_row">
<label class="field_name">Keterangan (MAKS 50 KARAKTER)</label>
<div class="field">
<textarea  placeholder="KETERANGAN CUTI" id="ket" name="ket" class="span12" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
</div>

</div>
```

This my column in database

> id | npp | tgl_pengajuan | ket | status | mpwp

There's no error but it's can't be insert

sorry I'm forget put tag form in here
so thi is my full view

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/themes/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css" />
<script>  $(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker(); });
  function save(){  $.ajax({
  url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>cutimpwp/add/',     
  type:'POST',
  data:$('#frmsave').serialize(),
  success:function(data){ 
      if(data!=''){
       $( "#infodlg" ).html(data);
       $( "#infodlg" ).dialog({ title:"Info...", draggable: false});           
    } else {
       window.location="<?php echo base_url() ?>cutimpwp";   }
   } });  }
   function confirmdlg(){
      $("#confirm").dialog({
       resizable: false,
       modal: true,
       title:"Info...",
       draggable: false,
       width: 'auto',

       height: 'auto',
       buttons: {
       "Ya": function(){
         save();   
          $(this).dialog("close");
          window.location="<?php echo base_url() ?>cutimpwp";
        },
        "Tutup": function(){
           $(this).dialog("close");
        }
       }
      }); } </script>
      <div class="span6">
                    <div class="well grey">
                        <div class="well-header">
                            <h5>Tambah Cuti  </h5>
                        </div>
            <div class="well-content no-search">
                            <form id="frmsave" name="frmsave"  class="form-validate">


                    <h3>Detail </h3>


               <div class="form_row">
                                    <label class="field_name">mpwp</label>
                                    <div class="field">
                                       <input type="text"  name="mpwp"  class="input-large"   value="<?php echo set_value('mpwp'); ?>" placeholder="masukan nama"> 
                </div>
               </div>

               <div class="form_row">
                                    <label class="field_name">Keterangan (MAKS 50 KARAKTER)</label>
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <textarea  placeholder="KETERANGAN CUTI" id="ket" name="ket" class="span12" cols="40" rows="5" value="<?php echo set_value('ket'); ?>"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


               <div class="form_row">
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <a onclick="return confirmdlg()" class="blue btn">Submit</a>
                                        <a  href="<?php echo base_url() ?>cuti_mpwp" class="red btn">Cancel</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                 </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="confirm" style="display:none"> Anda Ingin Meyimpan data ini</div>
```

and follow your instructur

my conttroler

```
    public function add()
        { if($this->session->userdata('LOGIN')=='TRUE')
     { $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('mpwp', 'mpwp');
       if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $data['view'] = 'cutimpwp/add';
         $data['judul']='';
        $this->load->view('index',$data);
        }else {$this->load->model('Cutimpwp_Model');
   $this->Cutimpwp_Model->add();
  redirect('cutimpwp'); }}}
```

controller

```
 `public function add() {
  $npp = $this->session->userdata('NPP');
  $mpwp = $this->input->post('mpwp');
  $ket = $this->input->post('ket');
  $data = array( 'npp'=> $npp,
  'tgl_pengajuan' => date('y-m-d'),
  'ket' => $ket,
  'status' => 'P', 
  'mpwp'=> $mpwp);
   $this->db->insert('Cutimpwp_Model', $data);}`
```

Comment: Can you insert other data to tables in your database? Meaning, does user have permission to "write" to the database? Also, is error reporting turned on in in PHP?

Comment: yes, I can.
this user have permission to write it.
error reporting not turned

Comment: Check in application/config/database.php if `db_debug` is set to `true`.

Comment: T_T 
in my config
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;

Comment: comment your `redirect()` and replace it with a `die()` so you'll be able to see the error.

Comment: no form open or close on view it not going to submit any thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just do it where you load your model like so. Also do not see any form validation in controller. You need that if submitting stuff.

Please remember to use form tags on view did not see any.

Model

```
public function add() {

  $npp = $this->session->userdata('NPP');

  $mpwp = $this->input->post('mpwp');

  $ket = $this->input->post('ket');

  $data = array(
      'npp' => $npp,
      'tgl_pengajuan' => date('y-m-d'),
      'ket' => $ket,
      'status' => 'P'
      'mpwp'=> $mpwp
    );

  $this->db->insert('table', $data);    
}
```

When submitting a form you need to run codeigniter form validation. In the success part of form validation load model function.

You also may need to set function name in your routes.php

Controller:

```
<?php

class Name extends CI_Controller {

  public function index() {

  }

  public function add() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mpwp', 'mpwp');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

      // do something

    } else {

      $this->load->model('modelname');

      $this->modelname->add();

      redirect('yourpage');

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: still not insert
and  following your instructur

Comment: Have you set your sessions up in config.pho what version ci you using.

Comment: thanks your instuctur solve my problem
I was wrong writing
$ this-> db-> insert ('cutimpwp_model', $ data);
should be
$ this-> db-> insert ('cuti_mpwp', $ data);
cuti_mpwp this correct my table name